# string validation in snowflake.rlike function how it works

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select 
    rlike('0737-M02828','^\\w*$' ), 
    rlike('0737_M02828','^\\w*$' ),
    rlike('Madsg','^\\w*$' ),
    rlike('073702828','^\\w*$' );
```

I am looking for:

```
true, true, true, false
```

but get:

```
('0737-M02828','^\\w*$' )= False
rlike('073702828','^\\w*$' )=TRUE
```

Please suggest - My requirement to check string.

Answer (score 0):

same sql different shape:

```
select column1, 
    regexp_count(column1, '^\\w*$' ),
    rlike(column1 ,'^\\w*$' )
from values
    ('0737-M02828'),
    ('0737_M02828'),
    ('Madsg'),
    ('073702828')
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | REGEXP_COUNT(COLUMN1, '^\W*$' ) | RLIKE(COLUMN1 ,'^\W*$' ) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0737-M02828 | 0 | FALSE |
| 0737_M02828 | 1 | TRUE |
| Madsg | 1 | TRUE |
| 073702828 | 1 | TRUE |

The [REGEX pattern doc's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#general-usage-notes) says:

- \w: “word” character (a-z, A-Z, underscore (“_”), or decimal digit).
- \W: not a word character.

Thus if you use something like:

```
    rlike(column1 ,'^[\\w-]*$' ) AND rlike(column1 ,'.*[a-zA-Z].*' )
```

```
select column1, 
    rlike(column1 ,'^\\w*$' ) as _current,
    rlike(column1 ,'^[\\w-]*$' ) AND rlike(column1 ,'.*[a-zA-Z].*' ) as _new
from values
    ('0737-M02828'),
    ('0737_M02828'),
    ('Madsg'),
    ('073702828')
```

| COLUMN1 | _CURRENT | _NEW |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0737-M02828 | FALSE | TRUE |
| 0737_M02828 | TRUE | TRUE |
| Madsg | TRUE | TRUE |
| 073702828 | TRUE | FALSE |

Comment: Thank you so much @Simeon. Can use two condition with AND ,that's useful information.